# Validating ruby float/integer between 0 and 1

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a validation function that checks a variable to see if it is between 0 and 1

```
unless xff.between?(0,1)
  raise Puppet::ParseError, ("error message here")
end
```

If xff is 0.5 then it raises the error. How can I fix this so that it will accept float/integer values between (and including) 0 and 1?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `(xff >= 0.0) && (xff <= 1.0)`?

Comment: No, no reason. I'm very new to Ruby so I don't know what I'm doing. Would that work if xff was 0 or 1 (not 1.0)?

Comment: Yes. Floats and integers compare by coercing the integer into a float.

Comment: Why should it not work ? here is the output from terminal 
`2.1.1 :003 > 0.5.between?(0,1)
 => true 
2.1.1 :004 > 1.5.between?(0,1)
 => false 
2.1.1 :005 > `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me just fine for both, float and integer values:

```
-1.0.between?(0, 1) #=> false
 0.0.between?(0, 1) #=> true
 0.5.between?(0, 1) #=> true
 1.0.between?(0, 1) #=> true
 2.0.between?(0, 1) #=> false

-1.between?(0, 1) #=> false
 0.between?(0, 1) #=> true
 1.between?(0, 1) #=> true
 2.between?(0, 1) #=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the clearest ways to accomplish this is also the most straightforward:

```
unless (xff >= 0.0) && (xff <= 1.0)
  # raise error
end
```

You can also use a range and check for inclusion:

```
unless (0.0 .. 1.0).include? xff
  # raise error
end
```